# php and get method error

Tags: php, forms, get

I have this code :

```
<?php
if ($_GET["do"]=="success") {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
?>

<form action="file.php?do=success" method="post">
<input type="text"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

And I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: do in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.1\www\m\file.php on line 2

What do I need to do?

Comment: You might want to take a glance at [PHP error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: @budwiser: isn't the error already reported? Or are you suggesting to suppress the errors and pretend like it never happened? :P

Comment: @budwiser Given that the OP is seeing `E_NOTICE` errors, I'd say he's got it under control

Comment: Truthfully, that error isn't the end of the world.  But with PHP5.3 we are having to code more strict.  This is a good thing overall, but just make sure the var exists before moving down the code.

Comment: @DavidGuerra: Did you just say what I think you did? :o Suppressing errors / notices is NEVER a good idea. Either coding strict or not. Might be just be getting old though. Although I don't think so :D

Comment: @PeeHaa yup.  PHP is now trying to require stricter coding standards. They didn't really alert on previous PHP versions.  Just saying.

Comment: @PeeHaa Wasn't my point. I got the feeling that the OP was confused and I thought that it might be a good idea to get to know different kind of error levels in PHP. It's not nice to spend a whole day wondering an E_NOTICE, it's not the end of the world after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the index exists before trying to access it:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["do"]) && $_GET["do"] == "success") {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
?>

<form action="file.php?do=success" method="post">
<input type="text"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
if (!empty($_GET['do']) && $_GET["do"]=="success") {
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
?>

<form action="file.php?do=success" method="get">
<input type="text"><input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: @RobertasPalinskis use isset() rather than empty(). empty doesn't check if the value was  set and returns errors on unset values. null is not "not set";

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan this is incorrect. empty() does test for the existence of an object. Review example 1A or test it in code: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: I know the documentation. "not set" is not NULL

Comment: "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set." Empty will return no errors if a value is not set per the documentation.  So, if empty is not set or has no value, then the conditions are not met and no errors are produced.